# chmod Make URL forbidden outside the site

Tags: http, url, chmod

I need a `chmod` solution for if I set mode of a directory 'app' in

```
mysite.com/files/version1/app/index.html
```

I am loading the above url in my site page as

```
<html>
<object id="rfile" type="text/html" data="mysite.com/files/version1/app/index.html"></object>
</html>
```

The above should load if I do as above. But it should not load if I enter the url directly in browser.

Is there any way possible from `chmod`?

Comment: `chmod` can't be used to change whether a resource is served based on how it's linked to. `chmod` can only be used to prevent the web server from reading the file at all, in which case it won't serve it at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way.

You cannot detect if it was loaded simply by entering the URL or by any other means. This is how the HTTP protocol works.

[`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) is something different, it works on the file system level and you can use it to control permissions.